# IIS 6 doesn't recognize ~/Views/ web.config in ASP.NET MVC 4 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get working ASP.NET MVC 4 web application with ISS 6 and Windows Server 2003. I've followed the http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx and got MVC project loading. The problem is with Razor views that throw "

> The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' must derive from WebViewPage,
>   or WebViewPage.

I've checked [".. must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>" on MonoDevelop & MVC3 (OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971511/must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel-on-monodevelop-mvc3) and my web.config is available in /views folder. Howerver I don't know if this is an IIS or ASP.NET issue but Views/Web.Config files is not considered when the web app is running.

Am I missing something with configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need an explicit namespace inclusion for

> pageBaseType

This should be added to the web.config inside your Views folder.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I have these settings in my Wev.COnfig but the problem is that web.config is not considered when web app is running