# Issue in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have implemented an architecture in MVC in which I created two projects:
1_Presentation layer
2_Controller layer

I have implemented my own controller factory. The overall logic is perfectly working in MVC4. But as I implement the same architecture in MVC5 I get the following error.

> The view at '~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml' must derive from `WebViewPage`, or `WebViewPage<TModel>`.

I have searched for this error and applied the possible solution but still getting the same issue.

I applied this solution 
[The view must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127462/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel)
but unable to solve my problem.

Comment: without code, we cannot give you an answer. show us your code. we cannot read minds

Comment: Global.asax file of Presentation project:

Comment: possible duplicate of [The view must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127462/the-view-must-derive-from-webviewpage-or-webviewpagetmodel)

Comment: public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            RoutingManager.RegisterDefaultRoutesPortal(routes);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MFPortalControllerFactory());
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           // RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);        }}

Comment: possible duplicate of [“.. must derive from WebViewPage, or WebViewPage<TModel>” on MonoDevelop & MVC3 (OS X)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12971511/11683)

Comment: Applied the solution of this link but it's not solving my problem GSerg